# "Cancel Editing" button on chat looks strange

Tags: support, chat, design

I am not sure if this is intentional but I can't find another question highlighting this so figured I'd ask. In chat, when editing a message you've already posted, a "Cancel editing" button appears as follows:

[image]

In [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), at least (I've had a look in the DMZ but their red button appears fine over there) but it may also occur in other channels, the button stays in a state where it's either nearly transparent or perhaps supposed to be disabled?

I have noticed that in my browser at home the button doesn't become visible at all but that is running a beta version of Chrome so I put it down to that.

The button still works, clicking on it will cancel the editing process as intended, so this is purely an aesthetic issue.

Is the button supposed to look like that?

Comment: As I mentioned in chat, mine looks just like the other two buttons. Firefox 26

Comment: [Works fine here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10221029/looksnormal.PNG) on Chrome

Comment: No repro here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/f9CQp.png try stable browser version

Comment: Yeah, this is obnoxious. I'm not sure if it's the only trigger condition, but you can repro it pretty easily by quickly using the up arrow to edit a second-most-recent message (the fade-in animation never completes and it gets stuck like that for future edits).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd oh I am using a stable version at work, which is why I posted it!

Comment: @Flyk oh, my bad then! Guess Tim is right, something gets "stuck" with the fade-in/fade-out effects.